# Looking for QWERTZ KEYBOARD MAP to use in own operating system

Tags: c, operating-system, keymapping

does any knows where I can find such a key map?

I have already one(us key map), but I need the German Qwertz one.

For example this is the american one:

```
#define STANDARD_KEYMAP_DEF { 0, 0x1B, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' , '6', \
                          '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '^', '\b', '\t', \
                          'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', \
                          'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\n', KBD_META_CTRL, 'a', 's', \
                          'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', \
                          '\'', '`', KBD_META_SHIFT, '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', \
                          'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/',KBD_META_SHIFT, '*', \
                          KBD_META_LALT, ' ', KBD_META_CAPS, KEY_F1, KEY_F2, KEY_F3, KEY_F4, KEY_F5, \
                          KEY_F6, KEY_F7, KEY_F8, KEY_F9, KEY_F10, KBD_META_NUM, KBD_META_SCRL, '7', \
                          '8', '9', '-', '4', '5', '6', '+', '1', \
                          '2', '3', '0', '.', 0, 0, 0, KEY_F11  , \
                          KEY_F12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
                          0, '\n', KBD_META_CTRL, '/', KEY_PRNT, KBD_META_RALT, 0, KEY_HOME, \
                          KEY_UP, KEY_PGUP, KEY_LFT, KEY_RT, KEY_END, KEY_DN, KEY_PGDN, KEY_INS, \
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
                        }
```

Comment: finding the key map is easy, you just go to German amazon and look for a keyboard for sale then you can pretty much match it to the American keyboard. Problem is, how do you represent them. My guess is, you need to enable unicode at least and make your software unicode.

Comment: Wikipedia for a picture, or Linux kernel / X11 sources / X11 kbd maps

Answer (score 0):

According to [possibly the sole place on the whole Internet were you'll find relevant information about this](http://f.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15049), you can do one of two things:

- Look at `udev`/`X11`'s source. Apparently, the Linux keyboard driver just reports the scan code, and the application must know what it means.
- Do it the way `udev`/`X11`'s sources were written, that is, connect your WhateverLanguage keyboard, and let the code print the respective scan code each time a key is pressed. This way, you'll know what scan code maps into key `ß`, and you can hardcode it into your tables. You just need a bit of patience ;).

Comment: thank you that's a possible way. Can you help me find the udev directory in the linux kernel at github, I feel ashame but I can't find it :(

Comment: @student96: `udev`'s code is [here, in *systemd*](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev). BTW, you're *far* better by going the second way. You'ld need to decode `systemd` binary files *et al* to get `udev`'s values... Anyway, the other answer is probably better suited for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another suggestion: `loadkeys -d --mktable` outputs a nice table of the translation to keycodes in Linux. `dumpkeys -l` shows which keycode is bound to which keysym, then. Another approach is to run `showkey` and press the keys one is interested in (therefore, you need a german keyboard, obviously).

Part of the output of `loadkeys -d --mktable` on my system (laptop with standard german QWERTZ layout):

```
unsigned short plain_map[NR_KEYS] = {
    0xf200, 0xf01b, 0xf031, 0xf032, 0xf033, 0xf034, 0xf035, 0xf036,
    0xf037, 0xf038, 0xf039, 0xf030, 0xf02d, 0xf03d, 0xf07f, 0xf009,
    0xfb71, 0xfb77, 0xfb65, 0xfb72, 0xfb74, 0xfb79, 0xfb75, 0xfb69,
    0xfb6f, 0xfb70, 0xf05b, 0xf05d, 0xf201, 0xf702, 0xfb61, 0xfb73,
    0xfb64, 0xfb66, 0xfb67, 0xfb68, 0xfb6a, 0xfb6b, 0xfb6c, 0xf03b,
    0xf027, 0xf060, 0xf700, 0xf05c, 0xfb7a, 0xfb78, 0xfb63, 0xfb76,
    0xfb62, 0xfb6e, 0xfb6d, 0xf02c, 0xf02e, 0xf02f, 0xf700, 0xf30c,
    0xf703, 0xf020, 0xf207, 0xf100, 0xf101, 0xf102, 0xf103, 0xf104,
    0xf105, 0xf106, 0xf107, 0xf108, 0xf109, 0xf208, 0xf209, 0xf307,
    0xf308, 0xf309, 0xf30b, 0xf304, 0xf305, 0xf306, 0xf30a, 0xf301,
    0xf302, 0xf303, 0xf300, 0xf310, 0xf206, 0xf200, 0xf03c, 0xf10a,
    0xf10b, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf30e, 0xf702, 0xf30d, 0xf200, 0xf701, 0xf205, 0xf114, 0xf603,
    0xf118, 0xf601, 0xf602, 0xf117, 0xf600, 0xf119, 0xf115, 0xf116,
    0xf11a, 0xf10c, 0xf10d, 0xf11b, 0xf11c, 0xf110, 0xf311, 0xf11d,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf210, 0xf211, 0xf20e,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
};

static unsigned short shift_map[NR_KEYS] = {
    0xf200, 0xf01b, 0xf021, 0xf040, 0xf023, 0xf024, 0xf025, 0xf05e,
    0xf026, 0xf02a, 0xf028, 0xf029, 0xf05f, 0xf02b, 0xf07f, 0xf809,
    0xfb51, 0xfb57, 0xfb45, 0xfb52, 0xfb54, 0xfb59, 0xfb55, 0xfb49,
    0xfb4f, 0xfb50, 0xf07b, 0xf07d, 0xf201, 0xf702, 0xfb41, 0xfb53,
    0xfb44, 0xfb46, 0xfb47, 0xfb48, 0xfb4a, 0xfb4b, 0xfb4c, 0xf03a,
    0xf022, 0xf07e, 0xf700, 0xf07c, 0xfb5a, 0xfb58, 0xfb43, 0xfb56,
    0xfb42, 0xfb4e, 0xfb4d, 0xf03c, 0xf03e, 0xf03f, 0xf700, 0xf30c,
    0xf703, 0xf020, 0xf207, 0xf10c, 0xf10d, 0xf10e, 0xf10f, 0xf110,
    0xf111, 0xf112, 0xf113, 0xf11e, 0xf11f, 0xf208, 0xf203, 0xf307,
    0xf308, 0xf309, 0xf30b, 0xf304, 0xf305, 0xf306, 0xf30a, 0xf301,
    0xf302, 0xf303, 0xf300, 0xf310, 0xf206, 0xf200, 0xf03e, 0xf120,
    0xf121, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf30e, 0xf702, 0xf30d, 0xf200, 0xf701, 0xf205, 0xf114, 0xf603,
    0xf20b, 0xf601, 0xf602, 0xf117, 0xf600, 0xf20a, 0xf115, 0xf116,
    0xf11a, 0xf10c, 0xf10d, 0xf11b, 0xf11c, 0xf110, 0xf311, 0xf11d,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf206, 0xf206, 0xf210,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
    0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200, 0xf200,
};
```

If you take a value from there, e.g. `plain_map[3]` which is `0xf032`, and take only the least significant byte, then you get `0x32`, which, looking at (part of the) output of `dumpkeys -l` ...

```
0x0000  nul
0x0001  Control_a
0x0002  Control_b
0x0003  Control_c
0x0004  Control_d
0x0005  Control_e
0x0006  Control_f
0x0007  Control_g
0x0008  BackSpace
0x0009  Tab
0x000a  Linefeed
0x000b  Control_k
0x000c  Control_l
0x000d  Control_m
0x000e  Control_n
0x000f  Control_o
0x0010  Control_p
0x0011  Control_q
0x0012  Control_r
0x0013  Control_s
0x0014  Control_t
0x0015  Control_u
0x0016  Control_v
0x0017  Control_w
0x0018  Control_x
0x0019  Control_y
0x001a  Control_z
0x001b  Escape
0x001c  Control_backslash
0x001d  Control_bracketright
0x001e  Control_asciicircum
0x001f  Control_underscore
0x0020  space
0x0021  exclam
0x0022  quotedbl
0x0023  numbersign
0x0024  dollar
0x0025  percent
0x0026  ampersand
0x0027  apostrophe
0x0028  parenleft
0x0029  parenright
0x002a  asterisk
0x002b  plus
0x002c  comma
0x002d  minus
0x002e  period
0x002f  slash
0x0030  zero
0x0031  one
0x0032  two
0x0033  three
0x0034  four
0x0035  five
0x0036  six
0x0037  seven
0x0038  eight
0x0039  nine
0x003a  colon
0x003b  semicolon
0x003c  less
0x003d  equal
0x003e  greater
0x003f  question
0x0040  at
0x0041  A
0x0042  B
0x0043  C
0x0044  D
0x0045  E
0x0046  F
0x0047  G
0x0048  H
0x0049  I
0x004a  J
0x004b  K
0x004c  L
0x004d  M
0x004e  N
0x004f  O
0x0050  P
0x0051  Q
0x0052  R
0x0053  S
0x0054  T
0x0055  U
0x0056  V
0x0057  W
0x0058  X
0x0059  Y
0x005a  Z
0x005b  bracketleft
0x005c  backslash
0x005d  bracketright
0x005e  asciicircum
0x005f  underscore
0x0060  grave
0x0061  a
0x0062  b
0x0063  c
0x0064  d
0x0065  e
0x0066  f
0x0067  g
0x0068  h
0x0069  i
0x006a  j
0x006b  k
0x006c  l
0x006d  m
0x006e  n
0x006f  o
0x0070  p
0x0071  q
0x0072  r
0x0073  s
0x0074  t
0x0075  u
0x0076  v
0x0077  w
0x0078  x
0x0079  y
0x007a  z
0x007b  braceleft
0x007c  bar
0x007d  braceright
0x007e  asciitilde
0x007f  Delete
// ...
```

... is the keysym `two`. Pressing the two (non numpad) on my keyboard when running `showkey` prints

```
keycode 3   press
keycode 3   release
```

which confirms my (vague) understanding of what's going on there ( :D )

I'm sure with a small "translator program" (that you'd need to write), using the above information, you're able to get your mapping. (If needed I can provide the full files)

Comment: can you shortly describe how the translation program should work? 
I understand it this way: When I press a key I check the keycode, then I use it for the index of the plain/shift array and get a value, which has to be found in the dumpkey array. The dump key array is a 2d array and so i get the character I want to print to the console?